# How to Calculate OffsetLeft from parent excluding parent's left padding & border

Tags: javascript

Is there an easy way to calculate `offsetLeft` from its direct parent, but excluding padding and border width of the parent?

When I do this, the returned value includes the left border and padding width of the parent.

```
child.offsetLeft - parent.offsetLeft
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zUARP/)

I know I can simply subtract the left border+padding width of the parent, but this means I must to use `getComputedStyle` to retrieve those values, strip 'px' and convert to int, then finally subtract... Isn't there something better?

Comment: offsetLeft doesnt include the border but the padding there is only one exception for parent=table and parent=body where it also includes the border.
so you have to subtract there is no better way

Comment: It does include border and padding whether parent is table or body. Please see my fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look what I commented. I wrote the `offsetLeft` property of each element doesnt not include the border of the `offsetParent` with two exceptions as I wrote, here the `offsetParent` is `document.body` for each element.
so the calculation goes

```
child.offsetLeft - parent.offsetLeft - parent.clientLeft -
    parseInt(getComputedStyle(parent).paddingLeft)
```

because the difference of the two `offsetLeft` properties is including the parent border.

Comment: but thats not a unique way to do it because this only works if both elements have the same offsetParent.

Comment: i mean this will only work if both have the same offsetParent.. for example add to the parents css position:relative or absolute. then childs offsetParent becomes the parent itself. then the caluclation is wrong

Comment: If you already know a way to fix this issue, it'd be nice if you could post it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in Javascript since 1999 and so i have my own library like Jquery or other stuff so forget about the Application statement it's only a container for all methods and properties, i copy the stuff you need you can change that, four functions ELEMENT_pageX ELEMENT_pageY ELEMENT_distanceX ELEMENT_distanceY

ELEMENT_distanceX gives you the x difference between two different elements on the whole page. measured from the outersideLeft of B to the outersideLeft of A

```
var Application=new Object ();

//-------- Browser   Detection                                                                                
if (typeof ScriptEngine!="undefined" && ScriptEngine()=="JScript") 
     Application.BrowserType=0;                                     //--- IExplorer         = 0
else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1)               
     Application.BrowserType=1;                                     //--- Mozilla Firefox   = 1

 else Application.BrowserType=2;                                     //--- Google Chrome     = 2


/*  Calculates the pageX value of the element - exception: do not use with document.body or document.documentElement
    if one of the ancestors has overflow:scroll the position property of the ancestor has to be relative or absolute to give the correct value
pageX should be 0 when handing over, or it can be used as value transition */
Application.ELEMENT_pageX=function (element,pageX)
    {
    var parent=element.offsetParent;
    if (parent!=document.body)
        {
        pageX+=element.offsetLeft; 
        if (parent.scrollLeft) pageX-=parent.scrollLeft;
        if (parent.tagName!="TABLE")                //--- TABLE BUG
            pageX+=parent.clientLeft;
        pageX=this.ELEMENT_pageX(parent,pageX)
        }
    else    //--- parent==document.body
        {
        pageX+=element.offsetLeft;
        if (this.BrowserType==1) pageX+=element.clientLeft; //--  ------------------------ CROSS BROWSER COMPATIBILITY Mozilla
        }
    return pageX;
    }

/*  Calculates the pageY value of the element -  - exception: do not use with document.body or document.documentElement
if one of the ancestors has overflow:scroll the position property of the ancestor  has to be relative or absolute to give the correct value
pageY should be 0 when handing over, or it can be used as value transition */
Application.ELEMENT_pageY=function (element,pageY)
    {
    var parent=element.offsetParent;
    if (parent!=document.body)
        {
        pageY+=element.offsetTop;
        if (parent.scrollTop) pageY-=parent.scrollTop;
        if (parent.tagName!="TABLE")                //--- TABLE BUG
            pageY+=parent.clientTop;
        pageY=this.ELEMENT_pageY(parent,pageY)
        }
    else
        {
        pageY+=element.offsetTop;
        if (this.BrowserType==1) pageY+=element.clientTop; //-------------------------- CROSS BROWSER COMPATIBILITY Mozilla
        }
    return pageY;
    }

//-------- returns the difference in X (B-A) - do not use with element A or B is document.body or document.documentElement
Application.ELEMENT_distanceX=function (elementA, elementB)
    {
    return this.ELEMENT_pageX (elementB,0)- this.ELEMENT_pageX (elementA,0);
    }

 //-------- returns the difference in Y (B-A) do not use with element A or B is document.body or document.documentElement
Application.ELEMENT_distanceY=function (elementA, elementB)
    {
    return this.ELEMENT_pageY (elementB,0)- this.ELEMENT_pageY (elementA,0);
    }
```